# Select same rows in pandas multiple times

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of values of a column that I would like to select from a Pandas dataframe. This list has duplicated values, and I would like to select the corresponding rows in the same order as in the list and duplicated. For example, let's say I have this data frame:

```
  id    value    date
  1     0.5      01-01-20
  2     0.3      01-02-20
  3     0.4      01-03-20
  4     0.8      01-04-20
```

And this list :

```
dates=(01-01-20, 01-01-20, 01-02-20)
```

I would like the filtered data frame like this :

```
  id    value    date
  1     0.5      01-01-20
  1     0.5      01-01-20
  2     0.3      01-02-20
```

I tried to use the function `.isin()` but it does not take into account the duplicates. I guess this can be done in a for loop, but is there an "elegant" way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) what should be preferable like [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), because also working if no match (but necessary unique values of column):

```
dates=('01-01-20', '01-01-20', '01-02-20')
df = df.set_index('date').reindex(dates).reset_index().reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
print (df)
   id  value      date
0   1    0.5  01-01-20
1   1    0.5  01-01-20
2   2    0.3  01-02-20
```